# according to unity, all my cloud projects have been migrated to plastic SCM. What now? How do i access my files from before?

Tags: plasticscm

a while back, i became unable to push new releases of my game to cloud storage becuase apparently, all of them had been automatically transfered to plastic SCM. So then how do i access these migrated file depositories/ projects?

(i did make sure to make an export of the unity project)

Comment: Please reach support@plasticscm.com to help with the transition from Unity Collab to Plastic SCM.

Answer (score 0):

On Unity hub you have the option to open remote project by clicking the small arrow next to "Open" and choosing "Open remote project". You will find all your projects there.
[image: Unity hub UI]

If you want to take actions on your "cloud" or check who got access and all that permissions, you can view users in your organization the normal way on Unity's dashboard. Or you can head to [PlasticSCM Cloud Dashboard](https://www.plasticscm.com/dashboard/cloud), login and configure it as you wish.